# Why not running Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, outlook-2007

I wrote some code about sending Mail, Task, Appointment etc. For example you can add someone to your Outlook contact list over asp.net page. Every thing is OK on my local machine.

But if I publish my application to a server I cannot add anyone on my Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally not a good idea, as Microsoft themselves [state](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2):

> Microsoft does not currently
>   recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office
>   applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or
>   component (including ASP, ASP.NET,
>   DCOM, and NT Services), because Office
>   may exhibit unstable behavior and/or
>   deadlock when Office is run in this
>   environment.

Read the article to find out which obstacles await you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create an outlook/mapi profile on the server for the user that is sending the email. Note that since you're running on ASP.NET then the user sending the email will be the identity of the Application pool that the virtual directory of the web application is running in.

This is an [old article about creating a profile with outlook installed](https://wiki.brown.edu/confluence/display/CISDOC/Creating+an+Outlook+Native,+MAPI+Profile+for+Outlook+2003+on+Windows).